# Helper method always returns nil

Tags: ruby-on-rails, caching

I am attempting to cache the result for each user that is fed to the helper like so:

```
def user_color(username)
    cache_key = "Colors/#{username}"
    color = Rails.cache.read(cache_key)
    if nil?
      if Group.where(:members => username).desc(:priority).first == nil
        color = "none"
      else 
        color = Group.where(:members => username).desc(:priority).first.html_color
      end          # Write back to the cache for the next time
      Rails.cache.write(cache_key,color)
    end
end
```

The issue is, when I was not caching the result it would query the DB 20 times on one page load but with the caching it always returns nil. What is the problem?

Answer (score 0):

That's all branched inside of an if nil?

if nil? returns false, so there's nothing to return.

Answer (score 0):

Use `Rails.cache.fetch` - http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/Cache/Store.html#method-i-fetch (also make it prettier ;))

```
def user_color(username)
  Rails.cache.fetch("Colors/#{username}") do
    Group.where(:members => username).desc(:priority).first.try(:html_color) || 'none'
  end
end
```

and consider making this attribute a calculated column which would get updated on Group's before_save so you don't need to query it every time or cache it,

failing that, consider extracting this method to model, something like `User#html_color`